# Como mudar o hash do AdonisJS para md5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, md5, adonisjs

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma api em cima de um projeto legado utilizado por outros sistemas, e pretendo realizar uma autenticação utilizando o md5 em vez do bcrypt para comparar a senha apenas.

Já existe uma tabela de usuários com email e senha(em md5).

Em meu controller tudo ja esta funcionando tirando o fato do `await auth.attempt(usuario, senha)` comparar a senha utilizando bcrypt e não md5 como preciso.

Já tentei instalar o pacote do md5 e alterar nas configurações o `HASH_DRIVER` mas sem sucesso, a questão é não compreendo onde faço esse tipo de configuração, e se é possível, procurei pela internet desde ontem e nada ainda, espero uma luz por onde devo pesquisar.

Comment: Acho que esta biblioteca pode te ajudar: https://www.npmjs.com/package/adonis-md5hash

Comment: @Bins infelizmente ela esta desatualizada e não estou conseguindo implementar na versão 4.1

Comment: Você provavelmente terá que recriar o método `attempt` manualmente, tendo em vista que é muito improvável que o Adonis um dia te forneça isso nativamente, já que o `md5` não é seguro para esse fim.

Comment: @LuizFelipe você poderia me passar o caminho para recriar o metodo attempt ?

Comment: Você terá que criar a lógica do `login` manualmente... Selecionar a tabela de usuários através do nome do usuário e depois comparar as senhas.

Comment: @LuizFelipe entendo, é que com attemp eu recebia o token de autenticação, vou ver como gerar isso

Comment: Basta utilizar o [`auth.generate`](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication#_generateuser_jwtpayload_jwtoptions) após realizar as verificações.

Comment: @LuizFelipe realmente eu estava indo pelo caminho errado, realizei uma consulta manualmente e no sucesso gerando o token, de inicio é oque preciso, grato.